# Jenkins + Selenium random unknown server-side error during Karma+Mocha tests

Tags: javascript, macos, selenium, jenkins, karma-mocha

I have CI system. It consists of

- Jenkins Master server (version 2.60.2) running on Ubuntu 16.04
- Jenkins slaves Swarm Slave (version 3.4.1) running on Ubuntu 16.04
- Selenium hub (version 3.4.0) running on Ubuntu 16.04
- 4 Selenium nodes for Safari Browser (version 3.4.0) Running on Mac OS Siera 10.12.5 .
  With Safari 10.

Im testing Java Script project that uses Mocha+Karma to run tests.

Most of the time everything is working as it should.
But sometimes i have error like this one.

```html
{"message":"[get(\"http://my-jenkins-slave-hostname:9876/?id=39481\")] Error response status: 13, UnknownError - An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Selenium error: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 8 path $","status":13,"cause":{"value":{"stacktrace":"com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient...
```

It looks like some nodes of selenium sometimes fail randomly. 
All nodes are exact replicas of same image (Im using Mac Stadium to manage Mac OS nodes)

Ive tried to configure Karma to give more details in logs, ive tried to increase timeouts, but no luck. Error message stays the same.
How can i troubleshoot such problem?
Any ideas?

Comment: Such error are hard to debug, where is the error coming in? Your tests, grid logs or some place else?

Comment: Logs of selenium node looks ok. Ive compared logs form successful and failed build and they where the same. The error appears in karma logs. Ive tried to lower log level but message stays the same.

Comment: Can you manually query this url `http://my-jenkins-slave-hostname:9876/?id=39481` and see what results you get?

Comment: Hi sorry for long response. Had some family issues to attend to.It returns pretty large HTML page. Its javascript repo under test.

Comment: If it is returning HTML then not sure why something in code is expecting it to  be JSON? Hard to tell you something right now

Comment: Hi. Its really difficult bug to trace. Currently IE tests also failing. It claims that  some script causes to reload page which causes Karma to fail.Im gonna try this solution to debug the situation https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/1101